# Hypothesis Test on Contest, a problems?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, bernoulli-distribution

We have a contest 1 weeks ago. One question is a bit strange for us as follows:

$X\sim B(4,p).    $ for test $H_0:p=0.2$ versus  $H_1:p>0.2$.  if $X=4$, $H_0$ assumption is rejected. calculate type I error‌‌?

is there any hint by expert, how we can solve this contest question ?

Answer from sheet: `0.0016`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type-I error is a type of error that occurs when a null hypothesis is rejected although it is true(i.e.  $P(reject H_0|H_0)$)

Read more: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/type_1_error.asp#ixzz3XfOLYrFdr

As we reject $H_0$ only when X=4 and p=0.2 when $H_0$ is true,

Type-I error =$P(reject H_0|H_0)=P(X=4|p=0.2)=\binom{4}{0}0.2^4*0.8^0=0.0016$

Comment: would you please more describe ?

Comment: is it understandable?

Comment: It's not bad to add some detail on your answer for other reader :) but nice answer +1

Comment: I edited with pleasure! :)